# How to generalize the JSON in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, list

In my database, I have table called **library** which have columns like dependencies, email, alert, skipped and values are stored as

```
declare @library table (dependencies varchar(max),email varchar(max),alert varchar(25),skipped varchar(25) )

insert into @library values('{"jar":"azure.com","maven":"azure.com","maven":"azure.com"}','abc@mail.com,adv@mail.com',true,false)
```

I want to prepare JSON of these values which will look like as

```
{
 "libraries":[
    {
      "jar" : { "coordinates":"azure.com"}
    },
    {
      "maven" : {"coordinates":"azure.com" }
    },
    {
      "maven" : {"coordinates":"azure.com" }
    }
 ],
 "email_test":{
   "email": [
     "abc@mail.com",
     "adc@mail.com"
    ],
   "alert" : true,
   "skipped": false
 }
}
```

I have written have code as

```
select  (select  dependencies as [maven.coordinates] for json path) as libraries,
        (select email from library for json auto) as [email_test.email],
        alert as [email_test.alert],
        skipped as [email_test.skipped]
from library for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

And my JSON doesn't look like desired JSON

```
 {
   "libraries":[
      {
         "maven":{
            "coordinates":"{"jar":"azure.com","maven":"azure.com"}"
         }
      }
   ],
   "email_test":{
      "email":[
         {
            "email":"abc@mail.com , adv@mail.com"
         }
      ],
      "alert":"true",
      "skipped":"false"
   }
}
```

I am not able to achieve correct json . Can someboby please help me out here ?

Thank you

Comment: Are `jar` and `maven` known in advance?

Comment: yes @Charlieface

Comment: You can't have the same property `maven` twice in the same JSON, so your original JSON is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your existing query:

- `dependencies` contains the whole `coordinates` data, you can't just select the whole thing. Instead you need break it out and rebuild it. You can use `OPENJSON` as I have, or `JSON_VALUE`
- `email` is not valid JSON, it is a comma-separated list. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have `JSON_AGG` which would have made this simpler. So break it open using `STRING_SPLIT` and rebuild using a combination of `STRING_ESCAPE` (to escape any problematic characters) and `STRING_AGG` (to aggregate it again) and `JSON_QUERY` (to prevent double-escaping).
- `true` and `false` appear to be `varchar`, you need a `bit` value instead

```sql
SELECT
  (
      select
        j.jar as [jar.coordinates],
        j.maven as [maven.coordinates]
      FROM OPENJSON(l.dependencies)
        WITH (
          jar varchar(100),
          maven varchar(100)
        ) j
      FOR JSON PATH
  ) as libraries,
  JSON_QUERY((
      SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(value, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']'
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(l.email, ',') 
  )) as [email_test.email],
  CASE WHEN l.alert = 'true' THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END as [email_test.alert],
  CASE WHEN l.skipped = 'true' THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END  as [email_test.skipped]
FROM @library l
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ef8fdb87c59c62f52987fc8875d2df7)

Comment: And if I have a column containing values like {"spark.abs","sparkkkk"} then openjson will work ?

Comment: You need to add another property name in the `WITH` like this `[spark.abs] varchar(100)`. If those  property names are dynamic then it gets more complex

Comment: sorry you got misunderstood. like spark.abs is not property. like if another column like version and it have value like {"spark.action.aaa.com","spark.dea.com"} and my json will be look like { "spark_version":{ "spark.action.aaa.com","spark.dea.com"}. then OPENJSON work ?

Comment: Yes, sounds like you would need another `OPENJSON` subquery though. But it's unclear, so maybe create a new question

Comment: Okay. And just last question, If inplace of "Jar" above, there is another "maven", then It is not working. Then what to do ? @Charlieface

Comment: I have made a changes . can you check